# Excel Formula with Date from other cell

Tags: excel-formula

I count the number of Excel entries within a date with the following formula (ZÄHLENWENN = COUNTIF)

**=ZÄHLENWENN('2021'!L:L;">=01.11.2021")-ZÄHLENWENN('2021'!L:L;">30.11.2021")**

The Formula here is working but since I don't want to enter the date values ​​for every month of the year I have created a calculation with the function end of the month. (MONATSENDE)

How do I have to rebuild the formula when I get the two dates from two cells?

Cockpit E3: =MONATSENDE(D3;-1)+1 -> shows 01.11.2021

Cockpit F3: =MONATSENDE(D3;0) -> shows 30.11.2021

Cockpit D3: =01.11.2021 *(the only one entered manually)*

Unfortunately the outcome of my new formula is 0:

**=ZÄHLENWENN('2021'!L:L;">=Cockpit!E3")-ZÄHLENWENN('2021'!L:L;">Cockpit!F3")**

What did i do wrong ?

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put E3 and F3 as references to the formula - not as a string:

`=ZÄHLENWENN('2021'!L:L;">=" & Cockpit!E3)-ZÄHLENWENN('2021'!L:L;">" & Cockpit!F3)`

Tip: apply a name to E3 and F3 (e.g. FirstOfMonth, EndOfMonth) and then use the names within the formula. It then gets more "readable" - also for someone else who might maintain the project later.

`=ZÄHLENWENN('2021'!L:L;">=" & FirstOfMonth)-ZÄHLENWENN('2021'!L:L;">" & EndOfMonth)`

And maybe you should consider using tables for sheet 2021 (Einfügen > Tabelle)

Comment: I actually didn't know that you can define Names in excel, that is really nice to know.. and even better that it's working now. So thanks & Have a great day.